# Echo out php code from file without actually executing it

Tags: php, laravel

We are trying to create a webpage in laravel where people are going to be able upload their codefiles to our server, so that other users can watch the code and download it in codefiles if they like it. We however can't figure out the best way to make this happen.

I tried to just let php get a file and echo out the content. this worked well fot html and css, but with php nothing got displayed what so ever. someone mentioned using eval(), however i've read that it is a really bad idea to do so. Another idea would be to stash the code in a database and fetch it from there, which we have tried before, but it sort of over complicated, and avoiding to do so would be prefereable, and instead go directly to i file.

So my question is, do anybody have an idea that might work safely, both for us and our server and for the users.

Comment: [highlight_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php) might help

Comment: PHP is just text. echo it like any other text, subject to whatever rules your output environment has. e.g. if you're dumping the code to a browser, then you'll need `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Have you considered the crazy security implications of allowing people to upload scripts to your server? E.g. not storing it in a name chosen by the user (definitely not in a web-accessible directory and with an extension that will invoke the server's PHP or SSI output filters - otherwise they can execute their own scripts on your server! Use .htaccess/whatever to disable output filtering in the directory to be sure), white-listing types (and using detection) so that people can't upload trojans, broken JPEGs/MP3s to get code execution in broken iMagick/etc. instances, etc. etc.?

Comment: You sir, are a superhero! Worked perfectly! Do you know if there are any security risks with using it? Other than that it might echo out hardcoded passwords and stuff?

Comment: Yes we have considered the security risks, and know very little about actual threats. But i greatly thankt you for shining some light upon possible problems. As of right now, this site is meant for students on our school exclusivly, no other is supposed to have access to it. It's about 100 students tops, so hopefully we wont have to much issue with people intentionally trying to brake the site. However we will do what we can to stop people people from destoying stuff. maybe store the code itself on a different server? Also, will it help if you save files as .txt instead of for example .php?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
<?php
   // read Codefile
   $TheCode = file_get_contents($codefile);

   // Print it...
   echo htmlentities($TheCode);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the php code in a flat file like one with a `.dat` extension.
2. then read the file.

   ```
   $toechp = file(static.dat);
   echo $toecho;
   ```
3. You can allow .dat files to be downloaded on browser using headers.

   ```
   <?php
   $file = "http://example.com/static.dat"; 

   header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
   header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\""); 

   readfile ($file); 
   ?>
   ```

and you are done.